# Is there is any solution for jenkin chrome initiation?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-serenity

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'
System info: host: 'bluehole-Lenovo-V15-G2-ITL-Ua', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.0-46-generic', java.version: '9.0.4'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Configuration issue,  please set Chrome driver capabilities for head & headless mode of execution. then it should work perfectly.

something like this in

```
 chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
 chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
 chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

Comment: okay !!! but it dosen't work on my case where should i put this above code  in serenity.conf file or somewhere else.because i put this on serenity.confi its dosen't work

Comment: this error getting

Comment: Right before you initialize browser drivers like chromedriver, thats where you have to configure you chrome with certain options as called capabilities.

Comment: ok i,ll do that

Comment: Now it's showing the interactable element exception,No frame exception.and when we commit that part then it goes next element with same exception error.but its Working fine on terminal and console